# Multiple Entity Class with save data in multiple data in JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to create a Parent class and inherit in multiple Child class and store data in multiple tables in Spring boot JPA

```
class Base{
private a;
private b;
}
class ChildA{
private c;
private d;
}
class ChildB{
private e;
private f;
}
```

DB tables should be like below

Table A

a | b | c | d

Table B

a | b | e | f

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want you should use a `@MappedSuperclass` annotated abstract class that has the common attributes and have your entity classes extend from this class. See [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/) for the more information on how to implement.